# Author and department column wise other details row wise

Tags: ieeetran

I want following output while using IEEEtran class.

```
                                        Title
        Author 1                        Author 2              Author 3
        Department 1                    Department 2          Department 3
                                Institution/university
                                mail1,mail2,mail3,mail4
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: I feel that this won't qualify to be a duplicate. It is about `IEEEtran` and a proper method is needed for the job (not the `tabular` solution).

Comment: @HarishKumar a valid point, but I'm voting to leave closed, because the duped question is from the same OP and he didn't give enough information there for us to know it was `IEEEtran`. Ideally I think that question should be edited, not another one created.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\title{Sample paper}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{author 1\\ Department 1}%
  %\IEEEauthorblockA{} 
  \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{author 2\\ Department 2}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{Institution/university \\
                     mail1,mail2,mail3,mail4} \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{author 3\\ Department 3}
  %\IEEEauthorblockA{}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]